# Custom Rating Bar using Anko

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I've been exploring android development using Anko and Kotlin and had some trouble with the ratingbar, namely it size. I've tried to make it smaller using a custom style but themedRatingBar doesn't seem to work. So I've opted to make a custom ratingbar instead. I can't seem to make it work that way I want it to in that when I set it this way in the main activity:

> starRatingView{
>
> setRating(3)
>
> }

It does not output a rating of 3 and instead will output the default rating, which is zero.

> class StarRatingView: _LinearLayout {
>
> ```
> lateinit var imageViewStars: List<ImageView>
> private var starNum: Float = 0f
> private var starSize: Int = 5
>
> constructor(context: Context): super(context) {
>     initializeView()
> }
>
> fun initializeView() {
>     with(this) {
>         linearLayout {
>             relativeLayout {
>                 linearLayout {
>                     for (i in 1..starSize)
>                         imageView(R.drawable.ratingbar_empty)
>                 }
>                 linearLayout {
>                     for (i in 0..Math.round(starNum)) {
>                         imageView(R.drawable.ratingbar_filled)
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> fun setSize(starSize: Int){
>     this.starSize = starSize
> }
>
> fun setRating(starNum: Float){
>     this.starNum = starNum
> }
> ```
>
> }

Above is the code that I use to create the custom RatinBar. Trying to avoid using XMLs as much as possible and use Anko instead.

Answer (score 1):

if I can help here is a possible solution to show a custom RatingBar in a custom Alert using Anko library and Kotlin code...

```
var rateGave: String? = null
alert {
        title = "Rate your experience"
        customView {
            linearLayout {
                ratingBar {
                    numStars = 5 //here is to define the number of stars you want
                    rating = 4f //starting rate to show as the alert pop up
                    setOnRatingBarChangeListener { ratingBar, rating, fromUser ->
                        rateGave = rating.toString()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        positiveButton("Rate") { rate() }
    }.show()
}

fun rate() {
    println(rateGave) //now it's just printing out the rate to show that it's working fine, but in this function you can mange all the operations you need with the rating value
}
```

Hope it can be usefull.
Have a nice day :)